# how do I get a point between the numbers?

Tags: r, r-markdown

I want to get a point between my numbers but i don't know how?

code

```
iphone_maandprijs1 <- webpagina_tmobile %>% 
  html_nodes(css = ".text-large") %>% 
  html_text() %>% 
  str_remove_all("\\D") %>% 
  as.numeric() %>% 
  round(digits = 2)
```

result

[1] 5200 5400 4350 4550 5050 5900 5900 5900 5900 4850 5050 5500 5850 5900 5900 3550 5750 3750 5900 5900 3950

i want

52.00 54.00 43.50 enz. enz.

Comment: are they always 4 digits? then maybe divide by 100

Comment: This also helped! Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try a function from the `stringi` package

```
x <- c(5200, 5400, 4350, 4550, 5050, 5950)
stringi::stri_sub(x, 3, 2) <- "."
as.numeric(x)
[1] 52.0 54.0 43.5 45.5 50.5 59.5
```